# Docker: Connecting to external database

Tags: docker, hbase, docker-swarm

I have hbase instance running which my app connects, We are planning to move the app into docker container but keep hbase running outside of docker. I could make the my app running in docker container connect to hbase by using add-host option while running docker container as below

```
docker run -dit --add-host hbasehost:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx mydockerimage
```

However what we need is auto-scaling function of swarm, as we have multiple services to run, what is the correct way of achieving this if i want to run my app as docker service instead of individual container, i couldn't find any references to "--add-host" in "docker service"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Update**: As of docker `1.13` you now have a similar flag to add entries to `/etc/host`.

To add a host at service creation, you can use the `--host` flag:

```
docker service create --name myapp --host "hbasehost:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" --replicas 5 myimage
```

To update the service and add an additional host after its creation, you use the `--host-add` flag:

`docker service update --host-add "hbase:x.x.x.x" myapp`

You can also remove a host using `--host-rm`.

---

### Original answer

`--add-host` only appends an `host:IP` association in `/etc/hosts`.

You can switch from using `--add-host` to using **environment variables** with `--env` even though this will require slight changes to your app to use the environment variable instead of the hostname to connect to hbase.

```
# Applies environment variables for all tasks in a service.

docker service create --name myapp --replicas=5 --env HBASEHOST=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx myimage
```

Then you can scale the service using:

```
docker service scale myapp=20
```

Additional tasks should be able to use the environment variable to connect to hbase.

**Source**: *I'm an ex-Docker Swarmkit maintainer*

Answer (score 2):

If you pointed your `docker hosts` to an `internal dns server` or a `dns server` that you can create records on, You can create `A` record for your `hbasehost` on that `DNS server`. Containers will use `Internal Docker DNS` then fall back to `hosts DNS Server Settings`. But setting a record in `/etc/hosts` get the job done (weired).

My docker swarm node's `resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 10.110.1.25
nameserver 10.110.1.26
```

Now verify from inside one of the containers:

```
root@05d05f934c68:/# ping dc1.mydomain.net
PING dc1.mydomain.net (10.110.1.25): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.20.21.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=121 time=0.929 ms
```